# Video embed from Youtube in 3D

Tags: html, youtube-api

I have a video from Youtube that has an option to watch in 3D. Is there a way to embed that video to my page with 3D enabled, something like for HD?

```
?vq=hd1080

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/JQG6Egv-1pg?vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I try to search on google but with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to force it from the url parameters with `&feature=html5_3d`?

Comment: Yes, but no luck, still nothing.

Comment: This feature is disabled in embed player, as the HD button. In previous API it was possible to force HD button to appear passing ` ap=%2526fmt%3Dxxx` as parameter to the player but it is not anymore possible. Maybe in another release of the API it will be possible but I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

View it -> http://jsfiddle.net/HzG6g/ 
Try out this ->

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/JQG6Egv-1pg?vq=hd1080-VE?version=3&autoplay=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" width="560" height="315"></embed>
```

Comment: I look in your fiddle but video isn't showing in 3D. I try with Mozilla and Chrome.