# Html 3d video player

Tags: html, 3d, html5-video

Is there support for 3d videos like with VLC?

How it looks with HTML video player (Not wanted):

[image]

How it looks with VLC configured to play 3d (desired):

[image]

Is there a way to play any 3d video content with HTML?

I've browed a bit but haven't found a single result on 3d with HTML video players.

Is there a way to play it? Is there a 3rd party player? Or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are many 3D javascript templates like three.js( https://threejs.org/ ), babylon.js (https://www.babylonjs.com/) , copperlicht (https://www.ambiera.com/copperlicht/) , D3.js ( https://d3js.org/ ).

But this are ready made libraries for some 3D models. There is no way of adding an 3D video in html video player but you can surely embed an 3D video in your website.
One way of it is to using an youtube 3D video( for more refer : [Video embed from Youtube in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117506/video-embed-from-youtube-in-3d) ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into babylon.js https://www.babylonjs.com
It supports webVr and I think it has the split view like you want

Comment: the other way around. i would like to watch a movie with 3d cinema glases on my browser

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I misunderstood, Sadly I don't know of anything like this.